# Laravel Eloquent Array Loop

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have an eloquent query that is returning a 'show', and any 'show_ref's relating to it:

```
Show::where('show_slug','=',$id)->with('showrefs')->firstOrFail();
```

This brings back a nested array successfully, as follows:

```
{
   "show_id":2,
   "show_name":"ShowNo1",
   "show_logo":null,
   "show_facebook_url":null,
   "show_twitter_url":null,
   "show_website_url":null,
   "show_slug":"shown1",
   "created_at":"2014-09-27 11:57:32",
   "updated_at":"2014-09-27 11:57:32",
   "showrefs":[
      {
         "show_ref":1,
         "show_id":2,
         "show_start_date":"2014-05-16",
         "show_end_date":"2014-05-21",
         "show_year":2014,
         "show_common_name":"Mid May",
         "venue_id":null,
         "created_at":"2014-09-27 12:17:40",
         "updated_at":"2014-09-28 06:26:54"
      },
      {
         "show_ref":2,
         "show_id":2,
         "show_start_date":"2014-05-23",
         "show_end_date":"2014-05-28",
         "show_year":2014,
         "show_common_name":"Late May",
         "venue_id":null,
         "created_at":"2014-09-27 12:21:24",
         "updated_at":"2014-09-28 06:26:58"
      },
      {
         "show_ref":4,
         "show_id":2,
         "show_start_date":"2013-02-12",
         "show_end_date":"2013-02-13",
         "show_year":2013,
         "show_common_name":"Early February",
         "venue_id":null,
         "created_at":"2014-09-28 17:50:02",
         "updated_at":"2014-09-28 17:50:02"
      },
      {
         "show_ref":5,
         "show_id":2,
         "show_start_date":"2013-04-27",
         "show_end_date":"2013-04-28",
         "show_year":2013,
         "show_common_name":"Late April",
         "venue_id":null,
         "created_at":"2014-09-28 17:50:42",
         "updated_at":"2014-09-28 17:50:42"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I am trying to get from my view is the following format:

### ShowNo1 (show name)

#### 2014

list of any shows in 2014

#### 2013

List of any shows in 2013

Is there anyway this is possible from what I have coded so far? or have I gone about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `showrefs` function in your `Show` model somewhere that is defining this relationship.  @Armon's answer will work, but will run on the order of `O(n * years)` where `years` is the number of years you want to show.  Your example only has 2, but could be many more, and you can instead display your data in `O(n)` time.

You can `orderBy` in the methods defining relationships.:

```
// app/models/Show.php
public function showrefs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ShowRef')->orderBy('show_start_date', 'DESC');
}
```

If the tables you are joining together both contain a column which you want to order by, you may need to qualify the order by by appending the table name, as in:

```
->orderBy('`show_refs`.`show_start_date`', 'DESC')
```

After that, its just a matter of keeping track of the current year and noticing when it changes when looping over your data:

```
$show = Show::where('show_slug','=',$id)->with('showrefs')->firstOrFail();
$currentYear = '';
foreach($show->showrefs as $showref) {
    $showRefYear = strtok($showref->show_start_date, '-');
    if($currentYear != $showRefYear) {
        $currentYear = $showRefYear;
        // Output Year heading
    }

    // Output show details
}
```

Comment: Thanks @watcher, makes complete sense. Would the foreach's occur in the controller, or the view?

Comment: You would most likely pass the `$show` or its showrefs down to the view and perform a `@foreach` there. If you do it in the controller, you'll just wind up having to loop over them in the view again to display so it doesn't make much sense to do it twice.

Comment: I tweaked it, for those than come here after me. In the IF loop checking the `$currentYear` against those in the `$ShowRefYear`, I set the currentYear: `$currentYear = $showRefYear`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about Eloquent, you can use a simple function to walk through your nested array and collect your shows for a given year:

```
function collect_shows_with_year($shows, $year)
{
  $result = array();
  foreach($shows["showrefs"] as $show_ref)
  {
    if($show_ref["show_year"] == $year)
    {
      $result[] = $show_ref;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

$shows_in_2014 = collect_shows_with_year($shows, 2014);
$shows_in_2013 = collect_shows_with_year($shows, 2013);
```